# A CPAN module to parse google-style search query terms?

Tags: perl, search, full-text-search, standards, cpan

I want to turn a query string of the style:

```
my $query = q{recipe "with sauce" +eggs -pastrami};
```

Into a programmatic, [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL%3a%3aAbstract) query, to be used in [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass).

```
$where = { -and=>[ 
     'ingredients' =>[ { -like=>'%recipe%' }, { -like=>'%with sauce%' } ],
     'ingredients' =>{ -like=>'%eggs%' },
     -not => { 'ingredients => { -like => '%pastrami%' } }
]};
```

The above representation is just approximate. It's written by ear, untested and by no means syntactically nor conceptually correct.

What I'm looking for is some prior art on the subject, basic stuff. A CPAN module perhaps, or a C library that could be turned into a CPAN module. Is there a standard for such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic query parser in [KinoSearch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KinoSearch) does exactly that (though the default query boolean to join parts is OR, it can be set to AND). You have a few ways to approach stemming, token types, and wildcarding is possible but not built-in. It has a learning curve and the docs are a bit thin but I highly recommend the package. Besides being well done and terribly fast the author is extremely responsive to feedback, questions, and bug reports.

Comment: This is great, thanks. KinoSearch is really powerful. I've found a great usage rundown [in one of it's tests](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CREAMYG/KinoSearch1-1.01/t/601-queryparser.t). Now I just need to figure out how to turn that into a SQL::Abstract query.